Is matrix idempotent?
Let't say we have a matrix A such that $rank(A)=tr(A)$ and $rank(I-A)=tr(I-A)$. I tried to prove $A^2=A$ given these properties but I failed. Yet I strongly suspect that this matrix A could be idempotent because I tried to construct counterexample but I also failed, all my matrices were idempotent.
Could you please say if my guess is correct? If my guess is correct I would also be very interested in some justification.

What is $rk$? rank?

@RobertIsrael yes, renamed to rank to be more clear

using linearity of the trace you have $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(I_n-A) = n$, hence this  is a duplicate

@user8675309 indeed they are very similar but I will save this question because the answers here are very useful

Assuming $A$ is $n \times n$, this implies
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{rank} (I - A) = \operatorname{tr} (I - A) = \operatorname{tr} I - \operatorname{tr} A = n - \operatorname{rank} A \\
\implies \, &\operatorname{rank} (I - A) + \operatorname{rank} A = n.
\end{align*}
Using the rank-nullity theorem,
$$\operatorname{nullity} (I - A) + \operatorname{nullity} A = n.$$
Note that the nullspaces of $I - A$ and $A$ intersect trivially; if $x$ belongs to both nullspaces, then $Ax = 0$, and $0 = (I - A)x = x - 0 = x$. Thus,
$$\operatorname{null} (I - A) \oplus \operatorname{null} A = \Bbb{R}^n.$$
So, given any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, there exist unique $u \in \operatorname{null} (I - A)$ and $v \in \operatorname{null} A$ such that $x = u + v$, and
$$Ax = Au + Av = Au + 0 = Au + (I - A)u = Iu = u.$$
This makes $A$ a projection onto $\operatorname{null} (I - A)$ along $\operatorname{null} A$, and thus $A$ is idempotent.

thank you very much for detailed answer!

If this is an $n \times n$ matrices, $tr(I-A) = n - tr(A)$, so you want $rank(A) + rank(I-A) = n$.  Then $$\dim\; \ker(A) + \dim\; \ker(I-A) = (n - rank(A)) + (n - rank(I-A)) = n$$
Now $\ker(A)$ and $\ker(I-A)$ are subspaces whose intersection is $\{0\}$, so their sum is the whole space $\mathbb C^n$.  Thus $\mathbb C^n$ is the direct sum $\ker(A) + \ker(I-A)$, and $A$ is the projection on $\ker(I-A)$ corresponding to this direct sum, which is idempotent.
